# Custom WindowProc causes cross-thread exception

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I have a `TextBox` which can't be re-defined with a new class so that I can filter some messages in `WndProc`. So I have to use win32 function `SetWindowLong` to replace the default `Window proc` of the `TextBox` with my own `Window Proc`. So I can filter some messages in that `Window proc`. I've done successfully the replacement. Messages can be filtered in my `Window proc`.

However it's not complete because of the inconsistent exception `InvalidOperationException` (which saying my textbox is accessed from the thread other than the one it was created on). The strange thing is the exception highlights the line `base.Dispose(disposing);` in the overridden protected method `Dispose()` of my form created automatically by the designer.

Here is my code to replace to the default window proc:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, IntPtr proc);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int CallWindowProc(IntPtr proc, IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private delegate int MyWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
public int MyWndProcFunc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
   //Call the default window proc to test
   //However even this can cause the exception after some keystrokes or mouse selection.
   return CallWindowProc(defProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
IntPtr defProc;
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  Load += (s,e) => {
     defProc = SetWindowLong(myTextBox.Handle, -4, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new MyWndProc(MyWndProcFunc)));//GWL_WNDPROC = -4
  };
}
```

The form started OK, I can type some characters into my `TextBox`, however continue typing or try selecting text using mouse... can raise the exception I mentioned above. I don't find any documentation talking about this issue. I have also tried using `Invoke` to call `CallWindowProc(...)` in my own `MyWndProcFunc(...)` if the `myTextBox.InvokeRequired = true;` but there was no difference.

How can I dig into this problem further?

### Update

I would like to make it clear that, my purpose is want to replace the default window proc of a `TextBox` which can't be inherited or belongs to another application. But the code above is tested with a standard .NET `TextBox`. That's the first step to test before applying in the my project.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.ResetAutoComplete(Boolean force)
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in C:\Users\iec\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs:line 20
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
  at System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.DisposeThreadWindows()
```

Comment: I've tried it on Windows Vista & 7, 32- and 64-bit and I'm unable to reproduce the error, so far.  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @cokeman19 do you mean you run the code successfully? That's amazing. I'm using Windows 7 - Ultimate 64 bit. I updated the stack trace, please see.

Comment: @cokeman19 BTW, please read my question carefully, you have to try typing characters long enough for the exception to be thrown. Selecting text using mouse is the quickest way to throw the exception. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it runs successfully for me.  I clicked and typed in the textbox at the same time, to no avail.  It definitely looks like your form is being disposed.  To me, that says an exception is occurring somewhere.  A couple of ideas.  1) Turn on the option in VS to stop on all thrown exceptions.  2) In your SetWindowLong declaration, change your IntPtr parameters to be HandleRef.

Comment: @cokeman19 it's strange that it works for you. I've tried replacing `IntPtr` by `HandleRef` like this: `HandleRef hwnd = new HandleRef(myFormInstance, IntPtr_handle);` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why the textbox 'can't be re-defined with a new class'?  Is it in another assembly?  Is there something special about the way it's loaded?

Comment: @cokeman19 simply it's a control from the imported library. Not my control, otherwise I can hook everything in the protected method  `WndProc(ref Message m)`. It can't be inherited. There is another case in which I can hook into a `TextBox` on another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int CallWindowProc(...)
```

There are at least two reasons nobody can get a repro from your sample code.  The crash as shown in the call stack can only occur if you set the TextBox.AutoCompleteMode property.  And the bug in your code will only byte when you run your program as a 64-bit process, most SO users will use the default Platform target setting of x86.

Your declaration for CallWindowProc (and MyWndProcFunc) is wrong, the return value type is IntPtr, not int.  This can cause many quirky problems in 64-bit mode, albeit that the handle owner test failure wouldn't be on the top of my list.

Instead of using pinvoke, with forever the risk of subtle mistakes like this, the safer way to do this is to derive your own class from NativeWindow:

```
    private class MyTextBoxWindow : NativeWindow {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            // Customizations here
            //...
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

And use its AssignHandle() method in your Load event handler.  You should call ReleaseHandle() when you get the WM_NCDESTROY message.

Do **not** attempt to do this when the edit control is owned by another process.  The window procedure *must* live in the same process.  This requires injecting a DLL into the process, you cannot do this in C# since the process won't have the CLR loaded to execute managed code.  Native code is required, C is the usual choice.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. First, I changed `int` to `IntPtr` but it didn't work. The point here is the application target is x64, changing to x86 made it work. In fact, my textbox's `AutoCompleteMode` is `None`. Do you have any idea on how to make it work as an x64 application? About the `NativeWindow`, I didn't find any `Attach()` as well as `Detach()` methods, I also searched in `Object Browser` without find anything. Could you tell me how to find/gain access to them?

Comment: That was an oops, too many wrapper classes in memory.  I corrected it.  And no, I have no idea how to make it work in 64-bit mode if I can't get your repro program to bomb.  Nobody can.

Comment: Do you mean you can't reproduce my problem even the application target is x64? I'm still confused in the class derived from `NativeWindow`, is it used to replace my form inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`? If not, I don't have any clue on how to use it, Thanks. It's late now and I'm about to go to to bed. :)

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is isolated to the textbox in the library then it seems likely that something in that library is occurring on a second thread, which, by my best guess, is throwing an exception and ultimately trigger the dispose.

I would suggest looking in the library's source and try to identify if there is any multithreading occurring.  If you don't have access to the source, you can always use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), which can decompile as well as debug compiled assemblies.

Comment: however, I've just tested on a normal `TextBox`, if the test is successful, I'll apply on the actual `TextBox` and use the technique in my project which needs to hook into a `TextBox` in another application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new MyWndProc(MyWndProcFunc))
```

The trampoline will be destroyed when the garbage collector cleans up the managed delegate (`new MyWndProc`), but you aren't saving the handle to that delegate object so it becomes immediately eligible for cleanup.

You can't use a temporary expression here, you must save `new MyWndProc(...)` in a variable, and you must use that variable to manage the lifetime of the delegate, which is also the lifetime of the unmanaged shim/trampoline generated by `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.